# what does "&" means in operator overloading

Tags: c++

The following is a sample code for operator overloading.
what does the "&" means in the syntax

```
complx operator+(const complx&) const; ?
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class complx
{
      double real,
             imag;
public:
      complx( double real = 0., double imag = 0.); // constructor
      complx operator+(const complx&) const;       // operator+()
};

// define constructor
complx::complx( double r, double i )
{
      real = r; imag = i;
}

// define overloaded + (plus) operator
complx complx::operator+ (const complx& c) const
{
      complx result;
      result.real = (this->real + c.real);
      result.imag = (this->imag + c.imag);
      return result;

}

int main()
{
      complx x(4,4);
      complx y(6,6);
      complx z = x + y; // calls complx::operator+()
}
```

Comment: That's a reference. Any [decent introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should cover this.

Comment: Wikipedia also has decent information for beginners: [operators wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators)

Answer (score 2):

That means that you are passing a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) to a variable, instead of a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
(const complx&)
```

1. You are passing the value by reference.
2. Reference is just an alias to the original object.
3. Extra copy operation is avoided here. 
   If you have used 'pass by value' like :  (const complex ), then the copy constructor
   of complex is invoked for formal parameters.

Hope this helps to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

That is called as [pass by reference](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~sjac/c-to-cpp-info/references) and it is *not* specific to `operator overloading`. It is one of the ways you would pass arguments to a function [ 1.Pass by Copy, 2.Pass by address, 3.Pass by Reference ]. With `C` you make use of [`pointers`](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/)  when you want your original argument value to be modified when you modify it within a function. But `Cpp` also provides `pass by reference`, the name appended with `&` acts like an alternate name to the passed argument. [and also saves you from all that dereferencing and stuff associated with pointers]